# How to can I make my elements appear all on one line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, google-custom-search

The header for the website I'm working on has the company logo and a search bar.  I'd like the logo to appear on the right with the search bar to the left, filling the remaining available space.  Here's what it currently looks like, you can see the search bar has dropped to the next line:

[image]

And here's the code:

HTML:

```
<p class="body-one">
        <div id="navbar"> 
            <div id="navbar-content">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SsSkZjU.png">
                        <script id="search-function">
                          (function() {
                            var cx = '008943255139580210842:rssvb04mkxs';
                            var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                            gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                            gcse.async = true;
                            gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                                '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
                          })();
                        </script>
                        <gcse:search></gcse:search> 
                    </div>
                <ul>
                <li><b><a href="http://www.chaotixstudios.x10.mx/home.html">Chaotix Studios, LLC. - Since 2012</b></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.chaotixstudios.x10.mx"><u>Home</u></a></li> 
                <li><a href="http://www.chaotixstudios.x10.mx/games.html"><u>Games & Gaming</u></a></li> 
                <li><a href="http://www.chaotixstudios.x10.mx/social.html">Social Media</a></li> 
                <li><a href="http://www.chaotixstudios.x10.mx/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li> 
                <li><a href="http://www.chaotixstudios.x10.mx/products.html">Products</a></li> 
                <div id="search">
                </div>
            </ul> 
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
<div id="whole">
<head>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        <!-- 

        #navbar ul 
        { 
            margin: 7px; 
            padding: 5px; 
            list-style-type: none; 
            text-align: left; 
            background-color: #000; 
            font-family:Tahoma;
        } 

            #navbar ul li {  
            display: inline; 

        } 

            #navbar ul li a { 
            text-decoration: none; 
            padding: .2em 1em; 
            color: #666666; 
            background-color: #000; 
        } 

            #navbar ul li a:hover 
        { 
            color: #000; 
            background-color: #949494; 

        } 
            #navbar b
        {
            color:#666666;
        }
            p.footer-one
        {
            text-align:Center;
            font-family:Tahoma;
            font-size:14px;
        }
            p.body-two
        {
            font-family:Tahoma;
        }
            p.footer-two
        {
            font-family:Tahoma;
            font-size:10px;
            color:#B8B8B8;
            text-align:center;
        }
            #search-function
        {
            float:center;
        }
        --> 
    </style> 
</head>
```

This is a doctored image of what I'd like it to look like:

[image]

Comment: I suppose you could set the navbar's `display` to `inline-block`, float it right and make sure the width isn't too big

Comment: @cimmanon Yes, the second image has the Search Bar next to the logo.

Comment: In the future, it would be really helpful if you stripped your example code down to the smallest amount necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

instead of displaying the logo as an image, set it as the navbar-content background, left aligned with no repeat. Then set the navbar-content left padding enough to push the search bar off the background image.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the image as a background image and that will get you close, but I'm not sure if you can have it completely resizable without a flexbox. I'm still playing around with it, you can see here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wCdBa

(Note that for ease I replaced the google search code with a simple search input. There *could* be issues with the code that google injects as well)

Ok, after some further work, I believe I have it working. Note that I changed some of the html and a decent bit of the css. I tried to use a gist to show diffs, but the changes were a bit much, anyhow it at least shows them in the same place:

https://gist.github.com/whoughton/8985343/revisions

Final comment, the changes revolve around using the image as a background, and shifting to the border-box sizing and off of the top of my head I am not sure of the compatibility list of the border-box sizing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing Says you should be in reasonable shape with "modern" browsers.

Comment: I'm a newbie when it comes to this stuff. How should I piece that code together to form a functioning file?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the image in a div and float both that div and the search bar left.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the image out of the normal flow of the document, either via float or absolute positioning.  I chose absolute positioning here so that the image can be vertically centered:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/hobFc

```
#navbar-content {
  position: relative;
}
#navbar-content img {
  /* 100 x 31 */
  /* this is for vertical centering */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
/* not sure if this div is named dynamically or not */
#navbar-content #search-function + div {
  margin-left: 100px; /* the width of the image, add a little extra if you want */
  border: 1px solid;
}
```